# Prepend nameserver to resolv.conf in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, dns, 19.10, resolv.conf

I'm trying to add a nameserver to the top of my resolv.conf file on Ubuntu 19.10. I want to always have the nameserver 127.0.0.1 at the top.

I have created a created a new file called:

> /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dhcp.conf

and in that file I have added:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

And that kinda worked when rebooting the computer, however when the laptop goes to sleep the resolv.conf file no longer has my custom name sever prepended to the top of the file. What is the best way to get this change to stick in Ubuntu 19.10?

My /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file looks like this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=no
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

My /etc/resolv.conf file looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search lan
```

And the permissions on my /etc/resolv.conf file look like this:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Dec  6 08:09 /etc/resolv.conf ->
>   ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Output of systemd-resolv --status

```
 > systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 127.0.0.1
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: I'm not sure that adding 127.0.0.1 is the right thing to do, let alone creating 10-dhcp.conf. Do you have a DNS Server running on your computer? You might look at /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.

Comment: I have DNSmasq setup so I can resolve local domains.

Comment: If you check the file I specified, you might use the DNS=, and also change the DNSStubListener= to NO... as both dnsmasq and the systemd resolver will try to use port 53.

Comment: I've added DNS=127.0.0.1 and changed DNSStubListener=no and am not seeing anything changed in my /etc/resolv.conf file other than no DNS is working with those changes.

Comment: Did you install `dnsmasq` or `dnsmasq-base`?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I installed dnsmasq like this: sudo apt install dnsmasq

Comment: Show me `systemd-resolve --status`

Comment: systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 127.0.0.1
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
Truncated by comment system

Comment: Thanks for the `systemd-resolve  --status` info, but when put into comments, it's extremely hard to decipher. Please repeat the command, edit your question, and copy/paste the text in, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format the text into human-readable. However, I do see 127.0.0.1 as your DNS server for something...

Comment: Please see my answer. If it was helpful, please accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dhcp.conf`.

Edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and change:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` # edit file

This:

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

To this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=no
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

`reboot` # reboot computer

`systemd-resolv --status` # check DNS servers

Correctly now shows 127.0.0.1 as the default DNS servers, so it should now work with your dnsmasq installation.

Comment: When using this solution I get no DNS resolution at all. My /etc/resolv.conf file contains no reference to 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 does show up in `systemd-resolve --status`. What does `dpkg -l resolv*` return?

Comment: Edit the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file, and temporarily change 127.0.0.1 to 8.8.8.8, reboot, then do `systemd-resolve --status | grep -i dns` and see if it returns 8.8.8.8. See if `host www.ebay.com` works.

Comment: @kaptk2 status please...

Comment: Hi, I have made the requested changes to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and when I do a system-resolve --status | grep -i dns I do see DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 output however DNS resolution does not work. I get a "connection timed out; no server could be reached" error when trying to do a host lookup on www.ebay.com. No changes within my /etc/resolv.conf happen

Comment: @kaptk2 I suspect that it's a dnsmasq issue. Did you configure dnsmasq.conf after you installed dnsmasq? Temporarily uninstall dnsmasq, and revert the edits made to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, reboot, and see if dns works again.

Comment: I removed dnsmasq using `apt remove dnsmasq`, removed the changes to resolved.conf and rebooted my computer. DNS works again as expected. If I change `DNSStubListener=yes` dns works however my `/etc/resolv.conf` still only has a single entry in it of `nameserver 127.0.0.53` so I am not able to use dnsmasq to resolve .local domain

Comment: @kaptk2 at least we know it's a dnsmasq problem. 127.0.0.53 is the only address you'll find in /etc/resolv.conf when systemd-resolv is in charge. `systemd-resolve --status | grep i dns` shows more about the the real DNS servers. So, reinstall dnsmasq, look closely at dnsmasq.conf, and see if you can get it all working together. I don't have dnsmasq.conf here, but if I had to guess, I'd suspect you need to tell it what upstream DNS servers to use... along with interface/etc edits.

Comment: Hi @heynnema, how do we know it's a DNSMasq issue? DNS still doesn't work when I have `DNS=8.8.8.8` and `DNSStubListener=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. However if I turn `DNSStubListener=yes` things work

Comment: Yes, without dnsmasq, DNSStubListener should be YES. It only should be NO when two services are trying to use port 53 at the same time.

Comment: That makes sense, what I don't understand is when DNSMasq is running I'm able to resolve names when I query the nameserver directly `dig @127.0.0.1 www.ebay.com` resolves like it should. So that is why I think DNSMasq is working correctly

Comment: I don't know the exact linkage between dnsmasq and systemd-resolved. I'd suspect that dnsmasq.conf requires tweaking. Or maybe you have to install something like `libnss-resolv` or `resolvconf` or `libnss-systemd`... not sure.